# JS strict mode: Why does (only!) Edge complain when assigning style property

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, strict

Consider the following piece of code

```
"use strict";
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.className = 'bluebox';
el.style = 'background:blue; width:100px; height: 100px';
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(el)
```

Firefox and Chrome do create a Element

```
<div class="yolo" style="background: blue none repeat scroll 0% 0%; width: 100px; height: 100px;">
```

But Edge throws an error:

```
Assignment to read-only properties is not allowed in strict mode
```

What is happening here? Is the style attribute actually read-only and FF and Chrome behave incorrectly or do has Edge another concept of strict mode or...? How could I possibly find this out without asking here?

Comment: el.style.background = '' would be the way. Even if the other browsers do not complain - it wont work. Edge is actually correct on this.

Answer (score 1):

> What is happening here?

Not much.. you tried to wrongly assign a property collection.

> Is the style attribute actually read-only and FF and Chrome behave incorrectly or do has Edge another concept of strict mode or...?

No, if you would have set it as an attribute (setAttribute('style', '')), all would have worked. Yet the property however is an object - a collection and acts differently. So Edge is actually correct this time.

> How could I possibly find this out without asking here?

You could read and google:

https://www.w3.org/wiki/Dynamic_style_-_manipulating_CSS_with_JavaScript
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style

Exmaples:

```
elt.style.cssText = "color: blue"; // Multiple style properties

elt.setAttribute("style", "color: blue"); // Multiple style properties

elt.style.color = "blue";  // Directly

var st = elt.style;
st.color = "blue";  // Indirectly
```

Comment: Your link does not clearly tell that IE does not like the syntax in OP's question _Styles can be set by assigning a string directly to the style property (as in elt.style = "color: blue;" ),which forwards it as  el.style.cssText = "color:blue;"  , though  it returns a CSSStyleDeclaration object which is read-only.  ... , unless you wish to set the complete style in a single statement, since using the style properties will not overwrite other CSS properties that may already be set in the style attribute._

Comment: @James Thrope: Thank you for the tip. Appreciated :)

Comment: @mplungjan: That is strictly reading correct. Yet documentations usually tell what 'things do' and not all the cases of what 'things do not do'.

Comment: More often than not there is a compatibility chart at the end of mdn pages. Here not

Comment: Thank you mplungjan. Especially if you read the consider this very passage @Lain, wich you googled so herolike for me, you see that there is no need for such a mean tone. May question was not, how to avoid the error, but why it is raised. It's still not clear if FF and Chrome are less correct than Edge here and if your accusation of me using it simply wrong has any ground... Thank you for your efforts, but next time you want to answer like this please restrain.

Comment: @Paflow: There are no accusations and no offenses in any part of the answer. A man always gets the answers he deserves.